# Relation between distributions of linearly related random vectors.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-matrices

Suppose we have a random vector **x** with a well-defined and known distribution, p(**x**). Suppose also that we have the following linear mapping: **y = W x**. Is there a relationship between p(**x**) and p(**y**)?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.